# Getting Error While Updating Contacts from Outlook "The OData request is not supported."

Tags: outlook, ms-office, exchangewebservices

I am getting an error while updating Contacts from outlook Saying

**{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidRequest","message":"The OData request is not supported."}}**

Here is my JSON

```
             $Sync1 =array
    (

        "GivenName"=> "Manjit",

        "BusinessPhones"=> [
            "+1 732 555 0102"
        ],
        "HomeAddress"=> array (
        "Street"=> "Some street",
        "City"=> "Seattle",
        "State"=> "WA",
        "PostalCode"=> "98121"
    ),
        "Birthday"=> "1974-07-22"


    );

     $JsonEncodedData1 = json_encode($Sync1);
```

Here is my CURL Operations

```
       $headers = array(
        "Authorization: Bearer ". $_SESSION['$Acce-token'],
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-type: application/json"  
    );

    $id="AQ0zxW1WLhZfQcAHy4NAourakufhB9QQPde-QAAAgEOAAAAHy4NAourakuf
    B9QQPde-QAAAZ1NrwAAAA=="; //This is valid ID 


    $curl2 = curl_init("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contacts/".$id);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $JsonEncodedData1);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    curl_setopt($curl2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $curl_Response = curl_exec($curl2);
    curl_close($curl2);
```

How can i resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You are Missing preferred_username(Email Id Of That Particular User) You Have To Pass Email ID Also In Header While Pushing Contacts to Outlook

$headers = array(

```
"Authorization: Bearer ". $_Acceess-token,
"Accept: application/json",
"Content-type: application/json",
"odata.metadata: full",
"client-request-id: ".$_Client_ID,
"return-client-request-id: FALSE",
"X-AnchorMailbox: ".$_preferred_username_OR_EmailID
);
```